# A readfile buffer passing

Tags: c++, windows, parameter-passing, readfile, uart

This is probably trivial but I cannot get why I dont get the read back in my program. It seem to work fine for all the "complex stuff", and it says it has read 1 (character/byte), but I cannot get hold of it; it seems to be typ-matching problems (this is really weird the compiler g++ (i.e. gcc) btw  ).

How I alter different variants of Buf (as pointer, char, char array, etc) I cannot get hold of the input.

SO below is now the stripped code and sync read version. Which also should compile.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

//**********************************
//*******   M A I N  ****************
//**********************************

int main()    
{

HANDLE hComm;
int choice;

// non overlap test case (2nd last par = 0)

hComm = CreateFile( "COM4",  
                    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                    0, 
                    NULL, 
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    0,
                    0);

if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
   // error opening port; abort
   printf("open error COM4\n");
   }
else
   printf("COM4 open");

printf("\n Hi, this is a UART attempt:"); scanf("%d", &choice);


// build the control block

DCB           dcb={0};


printf("******dcb******\n");

dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcb);

if ( !GetCommState(hComm, &dcb)) printf("Get DCB error");  // I dont think this should be needed ?


if ( ! BuildCommDCB( "4800,n,8,2" , &dcb ) ) {
    // error
    printf("COM4 buidDCB -- error\n");
    return(1);
    }


printf("****here*****\n");

// put the control block into action

if (! SetCommState( hComm, &dcb )  ){
    // error
    printf("COM4 setCommState -- error:%d \n",(int)GetLastError() );
    return(1);
    }

printf("seem successfull \n");


/*************************************READ non-ASYNC TESTING ************************************/
/********************************************************************************************/

char  Buf[1];

/* initiate waiting for reading on UART */

DWORD dwRead;

// Issue rea


if ( ! ReadFile(hComm, Buf, 1 , &dwRead, 0)) {
      // Error in communications; report it.
      printf("ReadFile --- error:%d",(int)GetLastError());
}
else {    
   // read completed
   printf("read <%d>---%o--- \n",(int)dwRead,Buf[0]);
}


return 0;
}  //*** end main ************************************
```

Comment: While I appreciate your attempt to trim the question down to a reasonable minimum, this is still not a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the sense that it could be compiled and tested in isolation. I also think you should edit your tags. It seems that there is a lot of Windows (?) specific stuff in your code.

Comment: Ok, possibly I should try to substitute this text with a compiling cut down variant, will do soon if I dont get my head around this through some advice.

Comment: NOW for a big EXCUSE ME: the hardest buggs to  find are those that are no buggs. SBS (=shit behind the stearingwheel) was the trouble. It turns out that the code is fully viable, and  working.  Only that I was reading one single character, and I didnt realize that hyphen (oct55) was the first character i sent on the UART line. Also there was some initial rubbish on the line. (your remedy for [] was correct though) So sorry, thanks for all help. /georg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to kick yourself:  The problem is that the final `printf` (to display the value) should be:

```
  printf("--- immediate read <%d>---%o--- \n",(int)dwRead,Buf[0]);
```

Note the trailing **`[0]`** on `Buf`.

Alternatively, you could declare `Buf` as:

```
char Buf;
```

and then the call would be:

```
    if ( ! ReadFile(hComm, &Buf, 1, &dwRead, &osReader)) {
```

(with a **`&`** on `Buf`.)

Comment: Hi thanks I will try out that one (though I think I have tried that one). I  really have trouble in seeing the difffernce between char Buf and char Buf[], I realize the compiler see the latter as int while the former as char * passed as parameter.

Comment: No.  The compiler see one as a `char` (which converts to `int` in most expressions) and the other as "array of `char`" (which converts to "pointer to `char`" in most expressions).  Understanding the difference between "array of `char`" and "pointer to `char`" is critical.  I take it you mean you have "difficulty noticing" the difference rather than "difficulty understanding" ("seeing" could mean either).

Comment: Nahh, ok thanks; to me it speaks that C++ is a patch, it is a mix between "Yes we are going high level language (with all typing and stuff)" and while actually handling still low level implementation artifacts. However its  nonconstructive of me to go into that  "philosophical think".

Comment: I have now tried the array variant with char Buf[1] declaration, and the Buf[0] call parameter, but it renders me (octal) 55 for all reads (on the serial port I have a string of ascii arriving). It beats me :p.

Comment: Ah ha.  Right, so the Buf vs Buf[0] was a read herring.  a) What happens if you don't open the file "overlapped"; b) I really think we need a [mcve]

Comment: Thing is that the "complex part" seem to work like clockwork, both with immediate read and async/delayed read, only nothing intelligible is delivered. I cannot see any problem with the dcb either. Be back.

Comment: SO now I have changed the original code to a compilable short version with sync read (instead of the async). Still same read problem, while everyting seems work ok (as to return codes/error).

Comment: wow; now i note that Buf is actually "C++ keyword marked", or possibly, it is marked light blue as the other "reserved words" !!! could that be something (that is then a language deficit, language and complier relying on semantics of higher layer support tools to do the work !!!, had no clue that such a common variable could be reserved word, in case this is the case)

Comment: The stack overflow syntax colouring is marking it the same way as it marks ReadFile.  I suspect it is using initial capital to means something.  `Buf` is not a reserved word or reserved to the implementation or anything.

Comment: changed to other name, no change, at loss now.